# How to bring up a docker-compose container as privileged?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I was running my container with the command `sudo docker run --privileged container_name`. But now I'm using a YML and and the command `docker-compose up` to bring it up but I don't know how to add the `--privileged` flag when bringing up the container with that command. I already tried adding `privileged: true` to the YML but it doesn't work in that case.

Answer (score -51, accepted):

I solved it myself by doing the following:
in the `docker-compose.yml` file I have these two lines for specifying the image and container's name

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: my_image
    container_name: my-container
```

so to run it with the `--privileged` flag I used the command: `sudo docker run --privileged my-container`

Comment: Using `docker` command will not read `docker-compose.yml` contents. Only `docker-compose` will read it. This is probably one of the reason that motivates so many negative votes on your answer. It doesn't help that you've answered and accepted your own question with a blatantly wrong answer.

Answer (score 104):

There is an apposite parameter to use:

```
web:
  image: an_image-image:1.0
  container_name: my-container
  privileged: true
  entrypoint: ["/usr/sbin/init"]
  ports:
    - "8280:8280"
```

Comment: what version is this,  3.1 says unsupported

Comment: This should be the selected answer, as this is the proper way to do it for a docker-compose file as asked in the initial question.

Comment: Added `privileged: true` but I'm getting

`Error response from daemon: failed to create shim: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: process_linux.go:446: setting rlimits for ready process caused: error setting rlimit type 7: operation not permitted: unknown`

Comment: @Chris this occurs because the user running the command is not allowed to run containers in privileged mode, probably because the daemon is running in rootless mode.

Comment: why is it `apposite `?